# Facebook share not showing the thumnail image

Tags: facebook, image, thumbnails, facebook-sharer

Following is the code I am using to share my posts on Facebook. Everything is working properly but sometimes on some posts the thumbnail image is not showing.

```
<?php
$title=urlencode('Facebook Share Platform');
$image=urlencode('imagepath');
$summary=urlencode('Check This Out');
$url=urlencode('http://apps.facebook.com/yourapplication');
?>

window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=<?php echo $title; ?>&p[summary]=<?php echo $summary; ?>&p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&p[images][0]=<?php echo $imagepath; ?>', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
```

I have checked the URLs and everything I could but couldn't figure out the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your image at least 50x50 and with an aspect ratio of 3:1 or less?
You haven't really given enough information there to solve your issue, so I'm just guessing based on the most common issue i see

{edit:}
The 3:1 image ratio requirement is documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) and appears to be the OP's problem

Comment: There is something I forgot to mention. when the share dialog come up I tried to read the HTML of that dialog, and found that the HTML has my image but the divs showing that image are hidden.. can u help

Comment: To answer your question my image is bigger than 50x50

Comment: What's the aspect ratio? (height/width and width/height need to be less than 3.0)

Comment: @Igy, [where is this documented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502163/what-where-are-the-official-restrictions-on-ogimage-meta-data-for-facebook)?

Comment: @zzzzBov a few places, one of which is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ - `og:image - The URL to an image that represents the entity. Images must be at least 50 pixels by 50 pixels. Square images work best, but you are allowed to use images up to three times as wide as they are tall.
`